# Widget to post on facebook and twitter - dropbox kind of widget

Tags: facebook, twitter, facebook-like, facebook-wall, facebook-widgets

I was looking at Facebook's social plugins and cant figure out how to do something like what dropbox has done.

If you go to dropbox referral page, they have a textbox with some predefined text - the user can add or edit the content and then share on his/her facebook wall.

I have attached the screenshot as well

[image: dropbox]

Is there a code snippet that I can easily integrate with my website to post on facebook and twitter. Even if its paid - its fine.

Thanks for your help